# Angular 4.2.4 ngOnChanges not triggering from parent component

Tags: angular

I am facing strange problem with angular 4 ngOnChange Event. ngOnChange is not triggering When i reset value and set same value(before reset). I want to trigger ngOnChange Event after reset(i mean 0) value. Please Help to fix this

Working example and plunker link as mentioned below

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TfQqOyx7O6upytNjel2x?p=info)

```
import { Component, NgModule, VERSION, OnInit, OnChanges, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  template: `
  <button (click)="changeCountClick()">Change Count</button>
  <child-component (onCountChange)="onCountChange($event)" [count]="recordCount"></child-component>
  {{recordCount}}
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div *ngFor="let chg of eventCalled">{{chg}}</div>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent {
  recordCount: number;
  eventCalled: string[] = [];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.recordCount = 5;
  }

  changeCountClick() {
      this.resetCount();
    this.recordCount = 5; /*Not Working*/
  //    this.recordCount = 2; /*Working*/
  }

  resetCount() {
      this.recordCount = 0;
  }

  onCountChange() {
    this.eventCalled.push('called');
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: ''
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input('count') public count: number;

  @Output() public onCountChange = new EventEmitter<number>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.count.currentValue !== changes.count.previousValue) {
      this.onCountChange.emit(changes.count);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I would be interested to know what the actual reason is, what I belive is: On click of the button, a changes detection event will run to see if the previous value is same as cuurent value. But the `reset-set` code will run so fast that the change detection will see both the previous and current valus as `5`. Giving a timeout of even 10 miliseconds work, something like: `setTimeout(() ={this.recordCount = 5;}, 10)` after the reset.

Comment: @AshishRanjan, Do we have any other way/can you suggest alternative for this type of issue?

Comment: That will depend upon what you actually want to achieve through the code finally. For now it looks to me that you just want to call `onCountChange()` of the parent after an event is emitted from the child, but actually not receiving meaningful input, even though you emit the count. What you can do is have a flag in parent component and along with the `recordCount` send the flag also as input, just the difference will be that you can toggle the flag on every click. It will be really clear if you layout your full requirement

Comment: I am implementing pagination component. count represents total records count. Based on total records pagination will update. After records fetching from server user can sort by clicking button. When i do local sort i am getting issue i mentioned, because records count will be same. when i do remote sort some time will be take to fetch from remote, In this case it works good.

Comment: I don't get it? So if the user clicks once, then it should be sorted? And if he clicks again, the sort should be removed?

Comment: Yes, when user click sort will trigger. when user clicks again sort needs to remove

Comment: So, it has to go through the child component and come back again to parent? Does the recordCount actually change in this process?

Comment: You can have another Boolean flag as input value which you toggle on every click. When you reach ngOnChanges of child, always emit `this.count`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172778/discussion-between-user-27-and-ashish-ranjan).